# How can I prepare a sql-statement in a sql-statement in ZF2?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZF2 and I've got following problem :

> In a db-table I got two id's that refered to another table. And if I
>   select them, I want to show the names of the players, rather than the
>   id's saved in the table.

```
player (id, name)

board (id, playerA, playerB)
```

`playerA` and `playerB` are integers and holding the id of a player, from the players table. I've got along with the skeleton-app, but the only clause I can pass to `tableGateway->select()` is the where-clause.

Does anyone have an idea? how can I prepare a statement like this in ZF2?

```
SELECT id, (SELECT name FROM player WHERE id = playerA) AS playerA, (SELECT name FROM player WHERE id = playerB) AS playerB FROM board
```

The tutorials and references I've found all ends up with a JOIN. But that do not fit here, right?

EDIT:
The following is it, what works fine with the skeleton app

```
protected $select;

public function fetchAll()  {

$this->select = new Select();

$this->select->from('board')
    ->columns(array('id', 'kindOf', ...))
    ->join(['pA' => 'player'], 'pA.id = board.playerA', ['playerA' => 'name'])
    ->join(['pB' => 'player'], 'pB.id = board.playerB', ['playerB' => 'name']);

$resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($this->select);
return $resultSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is'nt a ZF2 problem but a SQL problem. You can write this for example :

```
SELECT id, pA.name AS playerA, pB.name AS playerB
FROM board
INNER JOIN player AS pA ON pA.id=board.playerA
INNER JOIN player AS pB ON pB.id=board.playerB
```

In ZF2 :

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('board')
       ->columns('id')
       ->join(['pA' => 'player', 'pA.id = board.playerA', ['playerA' => 'name'])
       ->join(['pB' => 'player', 'pB.id = board.playerB', ['playerB' => 'name'])
```

Comment: Sorry, i was ill for two weeks, now back to the living ones.

Comment: First of all, thank you for response. I tried to work this out and it finally works! I really should do some more joins, instead of the freaky statements i ve made above =)